# luacheck не распознаёт стандартные глобальные перменные и методы lua

Tags: lua

Когда я запускаю luacheck в своём проекте, он выводит мне сотни предупреждений о неопознанных глобальных переменных. Вот пример таких предупреждений:

```
accessing undefined variable _G
mutating non-standard global variable _G
accessing undefined variable pairs
accessing undefined variable ipairs
accessing undefined variable math
accessing undefined variable assert
accessing undefined variable print
```

... и так далее до бесконечности. Грубо говоря, luacheck вообще не понимает, что такое lua и я не въезжаю, это баг или фича!? Что я должен подкрутить, чтобы этого не происходило?

В принципе, я могу решить эту проблему, добавив в .luacheckrc весь список исключений, но это будет очевидным костылём.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался! Проблема была вот в чём: файл `.luacheckrc` у меня выглядел таким образом:

```lua
std = {
  globals = {
    -- Здесь мои глобальные исключения
  },
  read_globals = {
    -- Здесь исключения с доступом только на чтение
  },
}
```

Такой пример настроек приводится в документации к luacheck, но там не сказано, что эти настройки перезапишут стандартные переменные lua!

Вот так этот файл должен выглядеть чтобы всё работало как надо:

```lua
new_globals = {
  -- исключения
}
new_read_globals = {
  -- исключения
}
```